# Как парсить сайты с загрузкой при прокрутке?

Tags: android, парсер, jsoup

пытаюсь спарсить Яндекс.Картинки по определенному запросу, использую JSOUP. Вроде бы все хорошо, но грузит только первые 30 картинок, как реализовать загрузку при прокрутке?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрев код запроса, определил что для запроса на определенную страницу нужно добавить

```html
search?p=2
```

Например запрос "яблоки" в Яндекс.Картинки будет выглядеть так
https://yandex.ru/images/search?text=%D1%8F%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8
А запрос на определенную страницу например 18
https://yandex.ru/images/search?p=18&text=%D1%8F%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8

Answer (score 0):

99%, что на странице javascript при прокрутке и вызывает асинхронно подгрузку следующих картинок. jsoup - не эмулятор браузера, вызвать скрипт в нем не получится(возможно я ошибаюсь, конечно). Вам нужно что-то вроде вот [этого](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) использовать. А лучше вообще вообще не парсить ничего и использовать API, который есть и довольно прост

Comment: У Яндекс.Картинок нет api

Comment: Странно,Я  точно им пользовался. Осталась только эта страничка в память https://yandex.ru/legal/pictures_api/ Может в фотки переехал функционал?

Comment: https://pp.userapi.com/c855632/v855632942/8164f/yTLLYOgaGjM.jpg

Comment: Тогда остается только парсить постранично или попробовать использовать тот мнимый браузер... Собалезную)